# Texture Painting not working

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am just trying to start painting on my Characters Texture, but when I try to paint, nothing ever happens.

See the image below for my Set Up:
[image]

When I draw on either the left or right hand side, it should add color to the texture, but it won't.

Any Ideas why?

Comment: All the interesting stuff which could be the reason is hiding in the brush settings - check if something is changed in Texture rollout, Stroke rollout, Curve rollout, or create a new brush.

Answer (score 1):

You need a light in scene to see the texture, or go to the material and set it to 'shadeless'. I usually set up lights in a sphere around the object and then hide them so that my object is well lit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if there are no lights, and you are in textured view, it will automatically shadeless your model, Craig.

Comment: No it won't. I have observed that if you switch to paint a texture on a mesh that is not set to Shadeless in the material settings that it will be dark like that until you add lights. If you paint in the Cycles system, it is more likely to see something right away, though the N panel has a shadeless setting there.